# UFW - Port is reachable for everyone although only certain IP's are opened

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I run an Ubuntu 22.04 server on an VPS with a current version of UFW.

Further i run an docker instance with firefox - https://hub.docker.com/r/jlesage/firefox
The port is routed to 5800 to access this container from outside.

In UFW i did following steps:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default allow outgoing

sudo ufw allow from *MYIP* to any
```

Theoretically, only connections of my specific IP should be allowed now.
However, when I call the VPN server's public IP including port, I can still access the Docker container's web interface from any IP.

How can I make sure that only I can access this address? Should I also block the outgoing traffic?

Firewall is enabled.

Comment: Did you *enable* ufw, or just define the rules?

Comment: Make sure `ufw` is enabled with `ufw status` - by defualt it is *not* enabled.

Comment: Yes it is enabled - "Status:active".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got it.
It was the docker-ufw issue. Crap that docker exposes ports even with ufw, maybe they should communicate it somewhere.

This fixes the problem:
https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker